# Check if input is 0 and disable submit button if 0 - Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```js
app.controller('HelloController', function($scope) {
  console.log($scope.input1);
  console.log($scope.input2);

  if (($scope.op_option == 4) && ($scope.input2 == 0)) {
    myForm.$invalid;
  }
});
```

```html
<form id="calc" method="post" action="/" ng-app="myApp" name="myForm" ng-controller="HelloController" novalidate>

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-2">

      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="op1" placeholder="Enter 1st number" ng-model="input1" required>
      <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.op1.$dirty && myForm.op1.$invalid">
      <span ng-message="myForm.op1.$error.required">Number is required</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <select class="form-control" name="op_option" ng-model="oper">
        <option value="1">+</option>
        <option value="2">-</option>
        <option value="3">*</option>
        <option value="4">/</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="op2" placeholder="Enter 2nd number" ng-model="input2" required>
      <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.op2.$dirty && myForm.op2.$invalid">
      <span ng-message="myForm.op2.$error.required">Number is required</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Calculate</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I want this code to check if op_option is divide (ie. 4) and input2 is 0. So it will divide b 0. And thus I want to disable the submit button. The input2 is 2nd option and op_option is operation ie Divide in my case to disable button. Also the code console.log($scope.input1) shows undefined on the browser console page.
Please help to make this happen

Comment: You can use a submit listener on the form to check the values selected and input and, if unsuitable, prevent submission and advise the user of the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try below option. Hope this will solve your problem.

```js
// Code goes here
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('HelloController', function($scope) {});
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" 
    ng-disabled="oper == 4 && input2 == 0">Calculate</button>
  </div>
</div>
```